# How can I evaluate a certain integral numerically?

Tags: numerical-integration

[image]

The problem arises as value of $\gamma_0$ is very high (on the order of 10^13), whereupon $\exp (-\gamma_0\,h_a^2)$ is becoming very small and  ultimately zero. Can anyone help me to evaluate this using `NIntegrate`?

$k$, $z$, $\gamma_0$  are all constants.

Edit 1:

As some people asked for the code that I used, it is following:

```
Pt = 0.2511
R = 1
sigma = 10^(-7)
gammaa = (2*Pt^2*R^2)/(sigma^2)
beta = 12.06
l = 200
l + 5
z = 4.343/(beta*l)
k = 5.49
res = NIntegrate[
  Gamma[k, z*Log[Exp[1], (l/h)]]*Exp[-gammaa*h^2], {h, 0, 1}, 
  MinRecursion -> 30,  MaxRecursion -> 70, AccuracyGoal -> 350,   
  Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"]
val = Sqrt[gammaa/Pi]/Gamma[k]
```

( Here I have used "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo" method just because only this way I was getting any value except Zero)

Comment: Please add the code you’ve tried to your question. People will be more able to solve the problem if they have a easy starting point.

Comment: If  $h_a$ is a constant, how can you integrate with respect to it?

Comment: m_goldberg, yes, I added ha there by mistake, its not constant.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the `AsymptoticIntegrate` command:

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[Gamma[2, 3*Log[1/t]]*Exp[-γ[0]*t^2],{t, 0, 1}, {γ[0],Infinity,1}]
(*-(E^-γ[0]/(2 γ[0]))*)
```

In more complicated cases [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) may be applied.

Comment: The command `AsymptoticIntegrate[
 Gamma[4, z*Log[1/t]]*Exp[-\[Gamma][0]*t^2], {t, 0, 1}, {\[Gamma][0], 
  Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> z \[Element] Reals]` produces a large (but finite) output.

Answer (score 1):

Changing
substitution to integral and expanding with infinte sum we have:
$$\int_0^1 \Gamma \left(k,z \ln \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right) \exp \left(-\gamma  t^2\right) \, dt=\int_0^{\infty } \Gamma (k,z t) \exp (-\gamma  \exp (-2 t)-t) \, dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }
   \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\gamma }\right) \Gamma (k)}{2 \sqrt{\gamma }}+\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{1+j} z^k (1+2 j+z)^{-k} \gamma ^j \Gamma (k)}{j!+2 j j!}$$

Closed-form for series probably not exist.

```
$Version
(*"12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 9, 2020)"*)

f[k_] := (Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[Sqrt[\[Gamma]]] Gamma[k])/(2 Sqrt[\[Gamma]]) + 
Sum[((-1)^(1 + j) z^k (1 + 2 j + z)^-k \[Gamma]^j Gamma[k])/(j! + 2 j j!), {j, 0, Infinity}];
Table[f[k], {k, 1, 5}] // MatrixForm // Simplify

(*1/2 \[Gamma]^(-(1/2) - z/2) Gamma[(1 + z)/2, 0, \[Gamma]] ... *)
```

Formula only works for: $k > 0$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

**EDITED:**

```
f[k_, \[Gamma]_, z_] := (Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[Sqrt[\[Gamma]]] Gamma[k])/(2 Sqrt[\[Gamma]]) + 
Sum[((-1)^(1 + j) z^k (1 + 2 j + z)^-k \[Gamma]^j Gamma[k])/(j! + 2 j j!), {j, 0, Infinity}];

f[2, 10^16, 1] // Simplify(* for: \[Gamma] = 10^16; k = 2; z = 1 *)

(*(2 - 2/E^10000000000000000 + EulerGamma - 
ExpIntegralEi[-10000000000000000] + 
Log[10000000000000000])/40000000000000000*)

N[f[2, 10^16, 1] // Simplify, 20](* for: \[Gamma] = 10^16; k = 2; z = 1 *)

(*9.85464428820156595122359384126*10^-16*)
```

Comment: Al that is not effective in view of `\[Gamma] = 10^12; k = 2; z = 1;NMaximize[{z^k (1 + 2 j + z)^-k \[Gamma]^j Gamma[k]/(j! + 2 j j!), 
  j \[Element] Integers && j > 0}, j, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]` which produces "NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded." and `{3.62596*10^98, {j -> 9}}`.

Comment: @user64494. Probably you are right.OP will choose the best answer.:)

Comment: `f[2, 10^16, 1]` produces $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(100000000)}{200000000}-\frac{2-e^{10000000000000000} \left(-200000000 \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(100000000)-\text{Ei}(-10000000000000000)+\gamma +2+\log (10000000000000000)\right)}{40000000000000000 e^{10000000000000000}}.$

Comment: The power expansion is meaningless, since the integral under consideration can be found in analytic form, e. g. `Integrate[Gamma[2, Log[1/t]]*Exp[-\[Gamma]*t^2], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> \[Gamma] > 0]` produces $\frac{-2 e^{-\gamma }+\log (\gamma )-\text{Chi}(\gamma )+\text{Shi}(\gamma )+\gamma +2}{4 \gamma }.$

Comment: @user64494. The power expansion is  not meaningless, since the integral under consideration can be not found in analytic form, e. g. `Integrate[Gamma[8, z*Log[1/t]]*Exp[-\[Gamma]*t^2], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {\[Gamma] > 0, z > 0}]` produces `Input`.

Comment: @Mariusz
One problem is that, your code is valid only for integer K, but in my case, the _k_   is not necessarily an Integer.

Comment: @user64494 I could not get the the form that you mentioned as the output, it is only producing the input.